# How to correctly serve static/pupblic assets in with express and Serverless?

Tags: express, serverless

**TLDR**: my express app deployed via Serverless to Lambda doesn't reference the `favicon.ico` correctly.

I have a `public` directory containing the webbapp's `favicon.ico`.

The `index.js` serves static assets, `app.use(express.static('public'));`, and in my html head `<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">`.

and this works fine for when running locally.

But with Serverless, I have included a `serverless.yml` for deployment, but once deployed the favicon is tried and failed to be fetched from `https://blahblah.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/favicon.ico`

Though my app is on a stage `dev`,

```
(serverless.yml)
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs16.x
  stage: dev
```

And the rest of my app renders and references fine on `https://blahblah.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev` within the 'dev' stage.

How do I get this `favicon.ico` to deploy and referenced correctly for any stage of my Serverless deployments?